# filter for rows that meet multiple conditions in a column

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements, subset

I am trying to subset or filter for rows where an ID is associated with two values in the same column (there is a row for each "ID" and the associated condition "DIR")

I was not able to figure this out in dplyr filter or with the subset function

```
x <- data.frame("ID"=c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
              "DIR"=c("up","up","down","up","up","up","down","down","down","down"))
```

I have attempted variations on both:

```
subset(x, DIR=="up" & DIR=="down") 

x %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(DIR=="up" & DIR=="down")
```

What I would like is for all that remains to be the two rows for ID #2, given that it is the only ID that has both "up" and "down" in the DIR column

It is returning no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'ID', `filter` by checking `all` the elements of the `vector` (`c("up", "down")`) are `%in%` the column 'DIR'

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(all(c("up", "down") %in% DIR) )
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   ID [1]
#     ID DIR  
#  <dbl> <fct>
#1     2 up   
#2     2 down
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
i1 <- with(x, as.logical(ave(as.character(DIR), ID, FUN = 
          function(x) all(c("up", "down") %in% x))))
x[i1, ]
#   ID  DIR
#2  2   up
#3  2 down
```

Comment: this works great! thanks for taking the time to help!